# Vertical alignment (for IE!)

Tags: css, z-index, vertical-alignment, css-tables

HTML:

```
<div class="product">
  <a href="#" class="thumb"><img src="img/thumb_md.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.product .thumb {           
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 130px;
}
```

..works great in modern browser, except, ofcourse, IE!

Is there any workaround? The other solution I tried was position:absolute; bottom:0; but it interferes with the drop-down above where z-index doesn't seem to have any effect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use relative+absolute positioning instead. The barebones of that is:

```
a.thumb { display: block; position: relative; height: 130px; }
a.thumb img { display: block; position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
```

See [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

Comment: Tried that already, but like I said I don't want to use position:absolute; bottom:0; because it interferes with the drop-down above it where z-index doesn't seem to have any effect. Drop-down hides below these images.

Comment: Since only IE8 (running as IE8 and not in compatbility mode) is the only version of IE that supports display: table-cell. And if z-index is a concern, explicitly set it.